# Alternative to function.prototype.bind in callback

Tags: javascript

I am trying to avoid using `function.prototype.bind` in a project. I do not want to use a polyfill.

Considering the code below, is there a way to avoid

```
  this.foo = new Obj2(this.callme.bind(this));
```

in the scenario below?:

```
function Obj1(){
  this.value = 1;
  this.foo = new Obj2(this.callme);
  this.foo.doSomething();
}
Obj1.prototype.callme = function(){
   console.log(this.value);
}
function Obj2(callback){
   this.finished = callback;
}
Obj2.prototype.doSomething = function(){
   // Do something here
   this.finished();// obj2 will be in scope. Obj1.value will not be availble
}

var bar = new Obj1()
```

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid `bind`? It is quick, convenient, and standard.

Comment: Code runs on old mobile devices, according to MDN, some don't support it.
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: @Skarlinski Further down that page, there is [a polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Polyfill) that you can use.  Out of the 3 methods on this page (your original `bind`, the closure and the passing of the context in my answer), I'd prefer the `bind` approach...

Comment: @JamesThorpe It would also be my preffered choice. Boss Man saw the warning on page that polyfill is not 100% complete, and put his foot down. code is running on millions of devices and we have no idea what we will encounter in the wild.

Comment: @Skarlinski Fair enough!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new closure to avoid using `bind()`:

```
var self = this;
this.foo = new Obj2(function() { self.callme(); });
```

Comment: That’s kinda polyfill, isn’t it?

Comment: @idmean I don't think so. I didn't create a `bind` function to add to `Function.prototype`; it is just a different style of writing the code.

Comment: So Sleek!
Why do I need the self = this here?

Comment: @Skarlinski Because if you used `this.callme();` within the inner function, you're back to square one, so you need to keep a reference to the outer object around.

Answer (score 2):

Not without writing additional/arguably messier code - this sort of thing is what `bind` is there for.  As an alternative to the closure based approach in [dsh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31834707/791010), you could pass in the context to use to the other object:

```
function Obj1(){
  this.value = 1;
  this.foo = new Obj2(this.callme, this);
  this.foo.doSomething();
}
Obj1.prototype.callme = function(){
   console.log(this.value);
}
function Obj2(callback, context){
   this.finished = callback;
   this.context = context;
}
Obj2.prototype.doSomething = function(){
   // Do something here
   this.finished.call(this.context);
}

var bar = new Obj1()
```

This is how certain standard functions such as [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) work, where you can specify the object to use as `this` within the callback.  You may want to code `Obj2` so the context is optional, depending on your needs.

Comment: Thanks, I wanted modules to be completely de-coupled